# Why can complex conjugates be defined only on complexified complex vector spaces?

Tags: complex-numbers, vector-spaces

I am working with the following definition of complex conjugation of the complexified vector space:

> Given any real vector space $V$ and its complexification $V^C$, the complex conjugate $\overline{w}$ of an element $w = (u,v)$ of $V^C$ is defined as $\overline{w}:= (u,-v)$.\footnote{In our mnemonic notation, this keeps in line with $u - iv$ as the complex conjugate.}

My book (Szekeres's A Course in Modern Mathematical Physics) makes two claims.

> (1) This definition is natural (basis-independent) and (2) for an arbitrary complex vector space there is no way of defining a basis-independent complex conjugate.

Given (1) and (2), it follows that the concept of complex conjugation of vectors requires prior knowledge of the ‘real part’ of a complex vector space and that the complexification of a real space has *precisely* the required extra structure needed to define complex conjugation of vectors.

But then he goes on to claim that the above means

> (3) that there is no natural way of reversing the complexification process to produce a real vector space **of the same dimension** from any given complex vector space.
> I can't see how this follows, even granting (2).

**However, I don't see why (1), (2), and (3) must be true.** I suppose I can work on verifying (1), though I'm not sure how to prove it given the space of all posisble bases. (2) I have no idea how to even begin to prove -- how can I prove that every conceivable definition of complex conjugate is not basis-independent? (3) has a similar confusion for me as (2).

Comment: Elements of $V^C$ are pairs $(u,v)$ because you split $V^C=W\oplus \overline W$, aren't they? How is that split performed? can you propose a way to do it in any complex vector space?

Comment: I think the point is that there is no such way which is basis independent (which is my question), but I'm not sure how to see it. @JackozeeHakkiuz